# Javascript function not calling function passed in as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass one function into another so that I can call it when an ajax call has finished, but I get an error saying that the function I want to call is not a function.

**File1 (Loaded first)**

```
function functionOne() {
    //Some Code
}
```

**File2 (Loaded second and contains ajax call)**

```
function functionTwo(functionOne) {
    functionOne();
}

functionTwo();
```

I get the console error of `TypeError: functionOne is not a function`

My question is two fold:

1. Why is `functionOne` out of scope in the second function?
2. Is this the best way of ensuring the ajax call has finished before running my first function code?

Comment: How do you call `functionTwo` ?

Comment: *"1. Why is functionOne out of scope in the second function?"* Nothing's out of scope. You have a parameter named `functionOne` that shadows the global. *"2. Is this the best way of ensuring the ajax call has finished before running my first function code?"* Depends what you mean. You're not really showing what you're doing.

Comment: @Tushar Sorry, it is called afterwards. Amended

Comment: @squint What do you mean by "Shadows the global" ?

Comment: You're trying to access `functionOne` inside `functionTwo`. The problem is `functionTwo` defines a parameter with the same name as `functionOne`. The identifier name resolution is such that the variable/parameter *closest* to its point of use will be used. Therefore, you're using the function parameter because it blocks (shadows) the global with the same name. And because you're not passing anything to that parameter, it's `undefined`, which isn't a function. Just ditch that function parameter and it'll work.

Comment: ...either that or just pass `functionOne` as an argument to `functionTwo` like this `functionTwo(functionOne)`. It looks weird, but it's really just the same as passing any other argument, like `functionTwo(123)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `functionTwo`, you shadow `functionOne` as you declare it as argument: the code in `functionTwo` only sees this new variable, not the global one with the same name.

But your approach is the wrong one, it won't ensure the order of execution you're looking for.

jQuery's `ajax` function returns a [promise](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/), which is a way to deal with asynchronous functions and have some function be executed when an ajax call has finished.

If you want `functionTwo` to start an ajax call and then call functionOne, you may do this:

```
function functionOne() {
}

function functionTwo() {
    return $.ajax({ // don't forget the return
       // many parameters here
    }).then(function(data){
        // use the data here
    });
}

functionTwo().then(functionOne);
```

This ensures `functionOne` is called only after the ajax call started in `functionTwo` has finished.

If you want to use the old fashioned way and pass the function as argument, do it like this:

```
function functionOne() {
}

function functionTwo(callback) {
    $.ajax({
       // many parameters here
    }).then(function(data){
        // use the data here
    }).then(callback);
}

functionTwo(functionOne);
```

But it's 2015, you'd better start looking at deferreds and promises ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did look at the promise but wasn't sure exactly how to execute it. 

For future reference, if I did want to pass one function into another rather than shadowing it, how would I do this?